# Terminal labyrinth game in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ansi-escape

I was thinking of implementing a labyrinth game in Haskell - the labyrinth will be of ASCII symbols and I would like it to be colored - for example walls to be blue "#", coins to be yellow 'o' and so on, and I was looking at [System-Console-ANSI](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ansi-terminal/0.5.0/doc/html/System-Console-ANSI.html).

I would like to ask if it will be possible at all to do this with this packet and I was thinking how to refresh the labirynth when an action happens (for example it can have coins in it, represented by 'o' and when the hero steps on a coin, he gets it and it should disappear) - will claering the screen and printing the labyrinth again do the job smoothly?

Can you please give me some ideas and maybe packets if System Console ANSI won't do the job? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Have a look at [The Caves of Clojure](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2012/07/caves-of-clojure-01/), a roguelike written in Clojure. While it is not Haskell, it should give you some ideas nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I will read it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at vty-ui at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vty-ui and http://jtdaugherty.github.com/vty-ui/. There's a very good user's manual for it. I've only played with it a little, but I think it would be well suited to your application.